# Material-UI List items scroll on top of AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material-UI (http://material-ui.com) for React.JS to make a mobile app. I have a problem with list items scrolling their content on top of the app bar. Other content (e.g. ordinary paragraph text in a <Paper/>) scrolls fine.

This picture shows how scrolled content gets on top of the app bar:

[image]

While these pictures show some added ordinary text (source below) which scroll fine:

[image]

"Some text" elements scrolled correctly under the AppBar:

[image]

"Ordinary" text (i.e. not text produced from ListItem properties) scrolls fine:

[image]

This is the main list rendering code:

```
renderConcerts() {
    return this.props.search.list.map((concert) => {
        return (
            <ListItem key={concert.id}
              primaryText={concert.work}
              secondaryText={concert.composer}
            />
        )
    });
}
renderContent() {
    console.log("renderContent ", this.props.search.classifier);
    const style = {
        margin: 12,
    };
    ....

    return <div id="mypaper">
      <p>Some text1</p>
      <Paper style={style}>
        <p>Some text2</p>
        <div className="content">
          <p>Some text3</p>
          <List>
            {this.renderConcerts()}
          </List>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </div>;
}

render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
        <div>
            <ResultHeader/>
            {this.renderContent()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The ResultHeader component:

```
export const ResultHeader = (props) =>
    <header>
        <AppBar
            title="Results"
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={hashHistory.goBack}
            iconElementLeft={<IconButton><ArrowBack /></IconButton>}
        />
    </header>;
```

Styling:

```
#mypaper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
    overflow: auto; !important;
}
.content {
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 26pt;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
.content table, .season tbody {
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px ;
}
.content h2 {
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #19768F;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.content h3 {
    font-size: 14px ;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: #313C3F;
}
```

UPDATE: I tried adding z-index: 100 to AppBar, but it did not help anything:

[image]

Furthermore, replacing List with Table gives pretty much the same behaviour, i.e some content (heading and select box) is over the AppBar while other content scrolls nicely under it:

[image]

Comment: which version of `material-ui` do you use?

Comment: Version 0.16.7 (the newest per today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index: 100`, or more, if you need to `AppBar`.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, try to add `position:relative`, `z-index:1000` to appbar, and same, but `z-inex:100` to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Although not fixing the problem directly, it led me on the right track! The problem in my case was the <header> tag surrounding the <AppBar>. It had its own styling confusing the z-indices; when debugging z-indices I could see that the area with z-index 1000 was effectively scrolling together with the text out of the screen. Adding your suggestion of 1000 to the header instead (the header has position fixed), solved the problem, Thanks,